# How can I make these forms in the middle of the page width؟

Tags: html, css, frontend

How can I make these forms in the middle of the page width
[the Intended form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBmYY.png)

using pseudo elements before and after

and using this code:

```html
<body>
  <div class="cont">One</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Three</div>
</body>
```

Note I am a beginner with CSS

Comment: Please provide some code otherwise it is hard to answer your question. I will answer your question if you provide some code to work with.

Comment: thanks for providing some code مصطفى-34 as @Matthias suggested, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to assist further could you also please provide any current CSS you're using? Also could you specify the width you're trying to achieve in some kind of units, like pixels or percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing one of the content and see effect . Giving `margin-top/bottom` equal makes it vertically center align and `display:block;` with `margin-left/right:auto` makes it horizontally center

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid rgb(209, 208, 208);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2%;
  display:block;
  margin: 15% auto 15% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">hd</div>
  <div class="content">hd</div>
</div>
```